# Folder became empty in google drive and deleted files are not shown in trash

Tags: google-drive-api

All the files in my google drive folder got deleted and there are no copies of it in the trash. The folder was shared with multiple people. Is it possible to recover the files now or at least know who deleted the files.

Comment: no its not possible

Answer (score 0):

If it's also deleted from trash, you can't use [Files: untrash](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/untrash) so there's no way to recover them unless you have the infinity gauntlet.